# Vue2.x: How to dynamically render an element using a custom function?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I used to use React.js but currently I'm learning Vue.js.

Now I need to dynamically render a part of an element, so I tried to render an jsx like this:

This is a simplified example:

#### UserListView.vue

```js
<template>
  <UserList :users="users" :columns="columns">
</template>

<script>
import UserList from './UserList';

export default {
  components: {
    UserList,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      users: [ 
        { id: 0, name: 'Alice', age: 18, gender: 'F' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Bob', age: 18, gender: 'M' },
      ],
      columns: [
        { name: 'name', label: 'Name' },
        { name: 'age', label: 'Age' },
        // element with custom render function
        { name: 'gender', label: 'Gender', render: user => (
          <div>{ user.gender === 'M' ? 'Male' : 'Female' }</div>
        ) },
      ]
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

#### UserList.vue

```js
<template>
  <table class="UserList">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="column in columns" :key="`column_${column.name}`" :class="column.name">
          {{ column.label }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="user in users" :key="`user_${user.id}`">
        <td v-for="column in columns" :key="column.name" :class="column.name">
          {{column.render ? column.render(user) : user[column.name]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['users', 'columns'],
};
</script>
```

But this throws me an error:

[image]

So is there a way that I can pass a template into the child and tell it how to render with some arguments? Can it be done with `slot`? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: is there a reason you need to do custom render of user's gender like that instead of using v-if in UserList.vue?

Comment: It's a simplified example. I wish the original component is highly customizable that I don't need to modify the `UserList` to render each cell what I like. Its render behavior is determined by the parent instead of chaining every possibility in `UserList` itself.

Comment: Render element inside child from parent is what `<slot>` for, but I have no clue how to use `<slot>` for your particular use case.

Comment: Hey, maybe this is what you are looking for https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Comment: I've seen that one. `createElement` seems a little bit verbose. Wish there's a vue template / jsx way to do this :/

Comment: did you try  ``<div>${ user.gender === 'M' ? 'Male' : 'Female' }</div>``? vue will render it as string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that may fit your needs would be to use [scoped slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).  In this example I just moved the rendering logic to the template but you could render whatever you want in in the slot.

```js
const userList = Vue.component('user-list', {
  template: '#userlist',
  props: ['users', 'columns'],
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    userList: userList,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      users: [ 
        { id: 0, name: 'Alice', age: 18, gender: 'F' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Bob', age: 18, gender: 'M' },
      ],
      columns: [
        { name: 'name', label: 'Name' },
        { name: 'age', label: 'Age' },
        // element with custom render function
        { name: 'gender', label: 'Gender'},
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <user-list :users="users" :columns="columns">
    <template  v-slot:gender="{ column, user }">
      {{ user.gender === 'M' ? 'Male': 'Female' }}
    </template>
  </user-list>
</div>

<template id="userlist">
    <table class="UserList">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="column in columns" :key="`column_${column.name}`" :class="column.name">
          {{ column.label }}
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="user in users" :key="`user_${user.id}`">
        <td v-for="column in columns" :key="column.name" :class="column.name">
        <slot :name="column.name" v-bind="{ column, user }">
          {{ user[column.name] }}
        </slot>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

There's a slot exposed for each column and the user/column exposed through the scoped slot.  You can tap into it in the parent context by referencing the slot by name which is currently bound to the column name.

```
<user-list :users="users" :columns="columns">
    <template  v-slot:name="{ column, user }">
      render whatever in the name column
    </template>
    <template  v-slot:age="{ column, user }">
      render whatever in the age column
    </template>
    <template  v-slot:gender="{ column, user }">
      render whatever in the gender column
    </template>
</user-list>
```

Comment: I didn’t know you can nest `template` into an custom element with parameters. This is just what I needed. Thank you so much!